# In MeteorJs how do I refer to an existing mongo collection?

Tags: meteor, alanning-roles

I'm using alanning:roles module, this creates 'roles' collection.
How do I reference that collection on my application?

Basically what I'm trying to do is fetch a **single** role based on role._id.
ie. roles.findOne('idhere');

Looking at the alanning:roles [docs](http://alanning.github.io/meteor-roles/classes/Roles.html), they didn't include an api to get by id.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can access Roles collection via

```
Meteor.roles.findOne({_id:'yourID'});
```

[Snapshot of how can you check if it works via console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqumH.png)